Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
I'm following the instructions for code 1 dapp evoting on YouTube. When I follow the instructions up to 2:34:00, I replace the getPolls() function in the index and I get this error:error.
You can watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdomOLGBTdY&t=9298s
How can I fix this? Thanks everyone.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
